# Считывание строки из файла

Tags: c++, строки

В моем файле содержится строка "Название : faso". Мне нужно :
1)Считать строку из файла
2)Обрезать часть "Название : " 
То есть тем самым получить только "faso"
Как я пытался это сделать :

```
ifstream fin(path,ios_base::in);   //path - строка с именем файл
char b[50];
string test;
fin.getline(b,50);
int size = sizeof("Название : ") + 1;
for (int i = size; i < size + 10;i++) {
     string str = to_string(b[i]); // переменную str создаю чтобы проще было понять что я вставляю в конец test
     test.append(str);
}
cout << test << endl;
```

Но в итоге я получаю :

```
1151110011210100
```

Во-первых я не понимаю почему `sizeof("Название : ") + 1;` возвращает мне не 12 (длина строки 11 + 1) а 21! 
И когда я смотрю на мою b через отладчик , то моя строчка "faso" находится под индексами 19-22 в переменной b.

Comment: *"Во-первых я не понимаю почему sizeof("Название : ") + 1; возвращает мне не 12 (длина строки 11 + 1) а 21! "* - такое ощущение, что вы полагаете, что каждая буква занимает один байт.

Comment: @user7860670 насколько я знаю , строка есть массив char , а char весит 1 байт , поэтому я посчитал это логичным.

Comment: Правильно, однако это не значит, что буква занимает один байт или один `char`. Оператор индексирования типа `b[i]` кстати тоже принимает не индекс буквы, а индекс байта.

Comment: @user7860670 можете пояснить почему ?Если буква записывается в один char , а он весит 1 байт , то почему так происходит ?

Comment: *"Если буква записывается в один char"* - так в том то и дело, что большинство букв никак не умещается в один char, разве что вы сидите под DOS или Windows 95 и используйте древние однобайтовые кодировки типа 866 или 1251. Ознакомьтесь с [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) - буквы могут занимать от 1 до 6 байт, обычно 2-3, 1 - только ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы резал просто по ": " - это проще.

```
string getFaso(const string& s)
{
    if (auto p = s.find(": "); p != s.npos)
        return s.substr(p+2);
    return s;  // Или рустую строку, если не найдено
}
```

Можно обгрызть лишние пробельные символы, если они могут быть...

Ваши фокусы с `to_string(b[i])` мне вообще непонятны. Зачем вам преобразовывать код символа в строку?...

Comment: Я пологал , что b[i] будет char`oм , поэтому я пытался его преобразовать в строку и добавить в конец строки test

Comment: Ну да, он `char`, но ваше преобразование рассматривает его как целое число...

Comment: Я никак не мог преобразовать этот несчастный char в string. Все что я искал в инете было как преобразовать массив char`ов в строку.  Как можно одиночный char преобразовать в строку ?

Comment: Опять - **зачем??** `test += b[i];`

Comment: если  есть символ `с`, то строковое представлнеие можно иметь так: `string(1, c);` а можно еще добавить к пустой строке  `string s; s += 'c'`

Answer (score 0):

А я бы просто прочитал только то, что нужно:

```
string s;
// не думаю, что будет больше 1000 символов перед :
fin.ignore(1000, ':'); 
while (fin.peek() == ' ') fin.ignore();
std::getline(fin, s);
```